# overload JS' Object prototype in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have written a function to resize an image and it would be very useful to add it to the Image prototype. Here is the idea:

```
Image.prototype = merge(Image.prototype, {resize:function(h,w){resizing}})
```

Now this works great in google chrome and I can do very simply :

```
img = new Image()
img.resize(800, 600)
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in firefox, apparently the browser is not happy with me trying to overload the prototype.

Does anyone knows a way/workaround to accomplish that, so it'd work in firefox too ?

Comment: You can add method directly `Image.prototype.resize = function(){}`. Why you overwrite the prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `resize` method directly to `Image`, without `merge`

```
Image.prototype.resize = function(){}
```

It will be work fine, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0rwxubu0/)